# Datetime dataframe conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am able to convert this to datetime64[ns] while doing individually as a series, but when try to do it over dataframe I get this error:

```
df[['Date Range','ME Created Date/Time','Ready For Books Date/Time']]=pd.to_datetime(df[['Date Range','ME Created Date/Time','Ready For Books Date/Time']],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

| Date Range | ME Created Date/Time | Ready For Books Date/Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-05-2022 00:00:00 | 02-05-2022 14:31:37 | 11-05-2022 00:00:00 |
| 10-09-2022 00:00:00 | 06-09-2022 14:19:03 | 10-09-2022 00:00:00 |
| 10-09-2022 00:00:00 | 06-09-2022 14:19:03 | 10-09-2022 00:00:00 |
| 10-09-2022 00:00:00 | 06-09-2022 14:19:03 | 10-09-2022 00:00:00 |
| 10-09-2022 00:00:00 | 06-09-2022 14:19:03 | 10-09-2022 00:00:00 |

I solved it through apply method. But I wanted to do it directly with `.to_datetime()`.

```
df[['Date Range','ME Created Date/Time','Ready For Books Date/Time']] = df[['Date Range','ME Created Date/Time','Ready For Books Date/Time']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to use `to_datetime()` directly on the dataframe as shown above without `apply` method?
2. Is it possible for `to_datetime()` to return the output as 'Date' without the input timestamp & without the help of `.dt.date` accessor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way, but for sure it's one of the easiest to read :

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date())
```

Comment: actually your solution has 2 problems - it converts the series to Object while I wanted it to stay in datetime64 format & it's quite slow. While experimenting this one does the job: df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.normalize()) & it's quite fast. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: you were refering to dt.date in the question, so I used date as well, but you can use normalize instead. Apply does an operation for the whole column, if this operation is vectorized, and I believe it's the case here, it should indeed be faster than applymap